# Extract date and time from text in GoogleSheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I am trying to separate the date and time alone from the text `Reported By:  Name 1   16/2/2021 9:44 AM`.

Currently, I am using the following formula:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A19,"(?:.+)(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4})")
```

However, the output is `6/2/2021` instead of `16/2/2021`.

I also haven't figured out the time part yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 01** Extract Date and time *Only*
Try this in `C2`, to get time and date extracted to their cells in one go, take a look at [This Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oBWu_KSD_lE2YchAsLws6T3rzgOYlRK_djGq3_Bp0zs/edit?usp=sharing).

```
={INDEX(SPLIT(TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(A2," ../.+"))," "),1,1),CONCATENATE(TEXT(INDEX(SPLIT(TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(A2," ../.+"))," "),1,2),"h:mm")," ",INDEX(SPLIT(TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(A2," ../.+"))," "),1,3))}
```

[image]

**Explanation**
1 -  in this formula we are matching with `REGEXEXTRACT` the first slash `/` and 2 `..` charchters before and every thing after the slash `.+` to grab 16/2/2021  9:44  AM

2 - [`TRIM`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094140?hl=en) any additional spaces this way we get the correct output even with diffrent spacing.

3 - [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en) using `" "` as a delimiter.

4 - [`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en) to get the column for each column resulted from the [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en) function in the Array `{}` {[`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en)([`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en)(`output,,1,1),`[`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en)([`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en)(`output,,1,2)`,[`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en)([`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en)(`output,,1,3)`} Like this,`1,1` Row `1` Column`1` to get `16/2/2021`.

5 - Format the output of column 2 of the [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en) function which is the "time" `9:44 AM` in this example with the [`TEXT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139?hl=en) function and set the format `"h:mm"`.

**Option 02**  Extract text, time, and date *all at once.*
Paste this in `B3`.

```
={TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A3),TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(A3," ../.+")),"")),INDEX(SPLIT(TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(A3," ../.+"))," "),1,1),CONCATENATE(TEXT(INDEX(SPLIT(TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(A3," ../.+"))," "),1,2),"h:mm")," ",INDEX(SPLIT(TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(A3," ../.+"))," "),1,3))}
```

**Explanation**

Option 02 is the same as Option 01 but we add this `TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A3),TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(A3," ../.+")),""))` in the start of the Array `{}` to get the text, we basically [`SUBSTITUTE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094215?hl=en) the outputed date from this formula `TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(A3," ../.+"))` with `""` nothing.

Answer (score 2):

### Answer

The following formula should have the result you desire:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A19,"\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}")
```

Alternatively, this formula also returns the time:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A19,"\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{2} [A|P]M")
```

And this one puts the date and time in separate cells:

```
={REGEXEXTRACT(A19,"\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}"),REGEXEXTRACT(A19,"\d{1,2}:\d{2} [A|P]M")}
```

### Explanation

In the formula you were using, the non-capturing group that begins your regular expression contains `.+`. The `.` matches any character and the `+` means that it looks for one or more matches. The `+` quantifier is greedy, meaning that it will match as much as possible.

As the regular expression begins processing, it starts matching every character from the beginning of the string, eventually matching the entire string. Then the regex begins trying to match `(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4})` but it can't because the entire string has already been matched. However, the regex notices it can backtrack with the `.+`, which starts giving up characters from the end of the string backwards. Eventually `(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4})` becomes fully matched when regex tries `6/2/2021`. Because `(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4})` has been fully matched, `.+` stops giving up its characters because of its greedy behaviour.

In short, because `.+` *can* match `Reported By: Name 1 1` (including the first digit of the date), it will.

The new regex I provide doesn't bother with the non-capturing group and so it doesn't have that issue. If a non-capturing group is necessary for some reason, you could use the following instead, adding a space in the non-capturing group.

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A19,"(?:.+ )(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4})")
```